# Entity Framework generated representation of a stored procedure signature is an Int instead of a record set

Tags: sql, linq, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

My stored procedure implementation is simple:

```
create Procedure [dbo].[GetNegotiationInfo] (
    @negotiationId uniqueidentifier
) As

    select NegotiationId, SellerId from NegotiationMaster where negotiationId = @negotiationId
```

Then I expected to be to write the following code after updating my model.

```
   using (var db = new NegotiationContext())
            {
var query = db.GetNegotiationInfo(NegotiationId).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

But I am getting the error "int does not contain a definition for FirstOrDefault()". I know that Entity Framework can have trouble generating complex stored procedures with temp tables etc but obviously my stored procedure doesn't get any simpler than this. Please note my stored procedure is this basic for my StackOverflow question and is not the actual stored procedure I will be using.

Comment: I think you are missing: System.Linq namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its all about editing the "Function Import" in the Visual Studio Model Browser and creating a complex type for the return record set. Note, temp Tables in your stored procedure will be difficult for Entity Framework to inspect. see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896231.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Stored procedures always return an integer.  This is the status of the stored procedure call and will be set to `NULL` if not specified in the code.  The general approach is that `0` indicates success and any other value indicates an error.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190778%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is some documentation on the subject.

If you want to return a value from a stored procedure, use `output` parameters.

Alternatively, you might want a user defined function which returns a value to the caller.  This can be a scalar or a table.

EDIT:

I would suggest that you look into user defined functions.

```
create function [dbo].[GetNegotiationInfo] (
    @negotiationId uniqueidentifier
)
returns table
As
    return(select NegotiationId, SellerId
           from NegotiationMaster
           where negotiationId = @negotiationId
          );
```

In SQL, you would call this as:

```
select NegotiationId, SellerId
from dbo.GetNegotiationInfo(NegotiationId);
```

EDIT (in response to Aaron's comment):

This discussion is about SQL-only stored procedures.  Entity Framework wraps stuff around stored procedures.  The documentation mentioned in the comment below strongly suggests that EF should be returning the data from the last select in the stored procedure, but that you should be using `ExecuteFunction` -- confusingly even though this is a stored procedure.  (Search for "Importing Stored Procedures that Return Types Other than Entities" in the document.)

Comment: Thanks, with this knowledge I have made changes to my question.

Comment: You are correct but this doesn't resolve the Entity Framework question where the asker is not getting the dataset they anticipate from the stored procedure. User defined functions (and the more easily composed table valued functions) are a good solution when working entirely within SQL, but I don't see how it solves Brian's problem.

Comment: See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx

> Notice that even though you selected None as the result, the generated method returns an integer which, according to the ExecuteFunction documentation reports the rows affected. The stored procedure returns the affected records by default because I have not included SET NOCOUNT ON. If NOCOUNT was on, then result of the function would always be -1.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the top of your procedure, the integer being returned is almost certainly the row count.

Like so:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[GetNegotiationInfo] (
    @negotiationId uniqueidentifier
) As

SET NOCOUNT ON;

select  n.*, 
        s.firstname + ' ' + s.lastname sellername, 
        b.firstname + ' ' + b.lastname buyername,
        substring(s.firstname, 1, 1) + substring(s.lastname, 1, 1) as sellerinit,
        substring(b.firstname, 1, 1) + substring(b.lastname, 1, 1) as buyerinit,
        s.email selleremail, b.email buyeremail,
        a.ADDRESS1
from    negotiationMaster n
        inner join usermaster s on s.userid = n.sellerid
        inner join usermaster b on b.userid = n.buyerid
        inner join PropertyNegotiation p on p.NegotiationId = n.NegotiationId
        inner join MyOtherDb..PROPERTIES a on a.property_id = p.PropertyId
where   n.negotiationId = @negotiationId


return;
```

Comment: A good guess but as @Gordon Linoff states below, stored procedures always return an integer.

Comment: But the Entity Framework only getting an integer result is most likely an issue with it receiving the count as an integer output and discarding the rest.

Comment: Can I ask, did you try my solution before saying a good guess?

Comment: See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx

> Notice that even though you selected None as the result, the generated method returns an integer which, according to the ExecuteFunction documentation reports the rows affected. The stored procedure returns the affected records by default because I have not included SET NOCOUNT ON. If NOCOUNT was on, then result of the function would always be -1.